# Как подключиться на удаленный MySQL сервер хостинга?

Tags: mysql

Можно ли подключиться к БД, которая находиться на хостинге с локального хоста?

Comment: Если на хостинге разрешен удаленный тип подключений к БД, что бывает в основном редко.

Comment: *Можно ли это как-то проверить?* А чем плохо "просто попробовать"?

Comment: да вот попробовал и не получилось)) Думал может можно как-то включить всё это дело

Comment: Подключение к удаленному MySql ничем не отличается от обычного, просто меняете IP адрес(возможно порт) в строке подключения на удаленный. Но как правило хостеры готовых решений не предоставляют подобной возможности из соображений безопасности.

Comment: Включить это всё можно, но для этого у вас либо должен быть собственный сервер (VDS/VPS с root'ом) и тогда смотрите в сторону ответа Igor Sergeevich, либо ваш провайдер должен разрешить на вашем тарифе такую штуку и тогда вам читать их мануалы и звонить в их техподдержку.

Answer (score 4):

> Можно ли подключиться к БД, которая находиться на хостинге с
>   локального хоста?

Можно подключиться если есть удаленный доступ к БД (в нашем случае к MySQL серверу), если нет доступа то его можно открыть следующем образом.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON database.*
TO 'user'@'%'
IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
```

> Можно ли это как-то проверить?

Да, можно. Самый быстрый и простой способ заменяете localhost на IP сервера. Если подключается то в вашем хостинга разрешен удаленный доступ к MySQL серверу.

Вместо этого я бы посоветовал Вам пользоваться Rest API который выдает ответ в виде JSON или XML.

Answer (score 2):

В файле конфига `mysql` найдите строку

```
bind-address = localhost
```

Закоментируйте ее

```
# bind-address = localhost
```

Добавьте правило для `iptables` которое будет отбрасывать все подключения к порту `mysql` кроме Ваших адресов.

Comment: Всё это правильно и ответу плюс, но мне кажется, что топикстартер сидит на шаред-хостинге и получает mysql из коробки.

Comment: @AK Спасибо:) А такие хосты это пичалька...